# My accepted answer was modified drastically. Is this allowed?

Tags: discussion, editing-help, rollbacks

My answer from July 2012 which was accepted as an answer was modified by a user 1 hour ago with edit summary "Removed irrelevant information to the original question. Use comments to share it". Please find the revisions at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11426318/revisions.

The editor has also modified the question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11426185/revisions

Is this allowed?

Comment: Answer has been rolled back to the original revision. This is what you should do if someone drastically edits your post and you don't agree with the edit - rollback.

Comment: It **is** allowed for them to make large changes, but it is also allowed for you to roll them back if you disagree with them. (If the community *overwhelmingly* agrees with the edit and disagrees with you, your right as the author can be overruled in some cases, but that's rare, and doesn't apply in this case.)

Comment: Just FYI to anyone looking at the revision history: there have been many edits since the one in question. OP is talking about edit #2.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That massive edit removed a lot of background information from the answer. It goes against the intentions of the user (you), so I rolled it back.

Keep in mind that you can *always* roll back edits on your posts if you disagree with them.

Comment: What background information? The question is about performance. 90% of the answer is about security implications of using console.log in production (which is a complete nonsense in the first place).

Comment: The content that was removed wasn't nonsense, @GajusKuizinas. But that's completely beside the point. It's not something you edit out. If you disagree with the contents / intention of an answer, downvote and / or comment. Don't just vandalize it.

Comment: It is a factual nonsense. There are no security implications of enabling logging on a client side application. If anything, it can reveal existing critical security vulnerabilities. But use of console.log itself does not create security vulnerabilities of any kind.

Comment: That's irrelevant. You don't edit a post if it's information is inaccurate. You comment / vote.

Comment: That edit on the question you rolled back was kinda okay.  The OP was asking two distinct questions, the last one almost begging for tool recommendations.  I'm not going to roll it back on you, but I'd suggest you take a second look at it.

Comment: The 2 paragraphs that were removed are nothing but a helpful bit of information. It doesn't make any security claims, it just points out that logging might not be desireable in production. If you disagree with that, ___comment or vote___. Don't utterly remove the information.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas If you disagree with an answer, why not write one yourself and let the users vote on both?

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Also, your edit comment was *Removed irrelevant information to the original question. Use comments to share it*. That's very bad practice. Remember that comments can be deleted at any time with no way to retrieve them. Information relevant to a post needs to stay *inside the post*.

Comment: @Cerbrus: "*You don't edit a post if it's information is inaccurate. You comment / vote.*" I only agree with that if changing it would effectively change the whole post. If the post contains a small, easily corrected factual error, then the best thing to do is to correct it. The problem is that what Gajus believes is "nonsense" is nothing of the kind. He's not merely correcting an error; he's directly interfering in what the answerer is trying to say.

Comment: @NicolBolas: that I can agree with.